# AS3 Profiling - Why do Object and Function counts increase when setting text

Tags: actionscript-3, profiling, flashdevelop

Firstly can some one please explain what is meant by `Object` and `Function` in a profiling environment.

Secondly, why does the Object and Function count increase when I repeatedly set the text property of a textfield:

```
override public function setLanguage(id:String):void
    {
        if (id == "en")
        {
            ui.title.text = _data.text.title.en;
            ui.title.direction = Direction.LTR;
        }

        else if (id == "ae")
        {
            ui.title.text = _data.text.title.en;
            ui.title.direction = Direction.RTL;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Laurent:

> Internally, TextField::text is most likely a getter/setter (since it needs to set a flag to update the text field display, also possibly update the HTML content, etc.) so when you set it you are effectively calling a function.

This means that TextField.text is implemented as a property getter and setter, so if you had to code it, you would see something like

```
private var _text:String="";
public function get text():String {
    return _text;
}

public function set text(value:String):void {
    _text=value;
}
```

Your `Object` count increases every time you reference (looking for a better word, don't kill me about this :P) an object (I trust you know what objects are), and your `Function` count increases every time you invoke a function.

So when you do something like

```
myTextField.text="Hello World";
```

you are *referencing* object `myTextField` and *invoking* its function `set text(String);`, causing your counts to increase by 1 each.

Comment: ah I see, thank you for the explanation. I was worried something more worrying might be going on ie new objects being created as the count increased.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, TextField::text is most likely a getter/setter (since it needs to set a flag to update the text field display, also possibly update the HTML content, etc.) so when you set it you are effectively calling a function.

What is it you don't understand about the difference between a Function and an Object? Could you be more specific?